# ¿Puedo dar formato de dinero a un TextInputEditText con un DecimalFormat? Android

Tags: android, edittext

En teoría lo que busco es sólo poner las comas de los miles y millones. Probé algunas veces utilizando el método 'addTextChangedListener' y 'afterTextChanged' pero muchas veces llegaba a un loop interminable.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder poner la coma de los miles y millones con el DecimalFormat?

Quiero añadir que tengo una app de un banco que tiene un EditText que luce de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me llama la atención lo que hace la app del banco que tengo, es decir, al ir introduciendo un número, lo va haciendo de derecha a izquierda, eliminando esos ceros que se ven en la imagen.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bajo este enlace encontraras la respuesta https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields

Comment: @TomaszVizaint Gracias por responder. El enlace contenía mucha información interesante sobre la apariencia de los Text Fields, pero no encontré nada con respecto a darle formato al texto (añadirle las comas a los miles y millones). Pero ten por seguro que dicho enlace me sirve mucho para otro tema. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que resolví el problema. En teoría falta pulir bien el código pero hasta el momento funciona bien (no le he encontrado fallas en las pruebas que le he hecho).

El código verifica (mediante varios if) que cumpla ciertos parámetros antes de entrar y darle formato al texto. Después de hacerlo, me aseguro que no entre en un loop interminable verificando un mismo texto una y otra vez, utilizando la variable 'doble'.

Monto1 es un TextInputLayout.

```
monto1.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                mostrarFormato(s.toString(), monto1);
            }
        });
```

mostrarFormato es el método donde se realiza la modificación del texto.

```
public void mostrarFormato(String str, TextInputLayout edittext) {
        DecimalFormat formateo = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###,###.##");

        if (!str.isEmpty()){
            if (!str.endsWith(".")){
                if (!str.endsWith(".0")){
                    if (!doble.equals(str)){
                        if (str.contains(".")){
                            int inicio = str.indexOf(".");
                            String decimales = str.substring(inicio);
                            if (decimales.length() >= 3){
                                decimales = decimales.substring(0,3);
                            }
                            str = str.substring(0, inicio);
                            str = str + decimales;
                            doble = formateo.format(Double.parseDouble(str.replaceAll(",", "")));
                            edittext.getEditText().setText(doble);
                            edittext.getEditText().setSelection(edittext.getEditText().length());
                        } else {
                            doble = formateo.format(Double.parseDouble(str.replaceAll(",", "")));
                            edittext.getEditText().setText(doble);
                            edittext.getEditText().setSelection(edittext.getEditText().length());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Si pueden observar, también le incluí lo de los decimales, ya que como lo que va a ingresar el usuario es un monto de dinero, dicho monto debe tener sólo 2 decimales.

En teoría, hace lo que promete. La cuestión ahora es que si al usar este método, pueda afectar el rendimiento del dispositivo, ya que tengo que poner 3 o 4 TextInputEditText y me preocupa que mi app pida tantos recursos para una simple operación matemática. Puedo notar que no se puede ingresar los números de manera fluida, hay que esperar más o menos un segundo para volver a ingresar otro número.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo pude hacer un poco mas sencillo aunque el mio esta aplicado a un EditText directamnete. supongo que tambien se le podria adecuar a un TextImputEditText.

```
        tuEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
                tuEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                if(tuEditText.getText().toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "").length() != 0){
                    DecimalFormat formato_numero = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###,###");
                    String salida = formato_numero.format(Integer.parseInt(tuEditText.getText().toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "")));
                    tuEditText.setText("$"+salida);
                    tuEditText.setSelection(salida.length()+1);
                }else{
                    tuEditText.setText("");
                }
                tuEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        });
```

basicamente desactivo el TextChangeListener para evitar que entre en un bucle y le aplico el formato de moneda(sin decimales). aun le falta pulir ya que al sobrepasar el 100.000.000 se crashea. pero para mis necesidades no necesito mas digitos y le aplico un `android:maxLength="12"` en el xml y funciona perfecto. ahí les dejo mi aporte.